# GDPR and cookies placed by share buttons

Tags: cookies

I'm trying to grasp everything I need to do and am allowed to do regarding the GDPR and cookies.

I'm building a client website that includes share buttons and the only cookies that aren't checked by my consent tool yet are the cookies placed by facebook and twitter when the share buttons are shown.

These are cookies placed by external providers that might include my personal data? I don't even know what is in those cookies.

Question: Is a website responsible for cookies placed by Facebook / Twitter when a user is logged in to those platforms on the same browser? So Do I have to disable the share buttons altogether until the visitor accepts statistics or marketing cookies? Or can I simply show the buttons because they've accepted the policy from said platforms elsewhere and thus given consent?

Comment: First of all, asking about such legal issues is rather off-topic here to begin with. That being said, many sites at least here in Germany have adapted a “two-click solution” for this - users will first be informed that such a social plugin would be loaded in a certain place, but the actual plugin is only embedded after they give explicit consent to that.

Comment: _“Or can I simply show the buttons because they've accepted the policy from said platforms elsewhere and thus given consent?”_ - just because you embedded for example a Facebook share button, does not mean that I as a visitor of your site must have ever visited Facebook before and given my consent to _anything_ in that regard. And yet, Facebook tracks even people who don’t have an account there across the net (“shadow profiles”), so this is very much something you should only embed on your site after my consent.

Comment: You could also switch to the pure link versions of the sharing dialogs nearly all such networks offer. Then you would not have any “live counters” any more of course, but you are on the safe side regarding cookies etc. - because as pure links, those do not create any connection to the respective network unless the user actively decides to use them.

Comment: @CBroe didn't realise that, my apologies. Client in this case insists on a specific platform to be used for the sharing and counters. I'll just completely disable the functionality without consent :) However, the consent given to facebook that im talking about is because the visitor is logged into facebook in that browser. When I check the cookies in an incognito browser facebook doesn't place a single cookie.

Comment: Not talking about incognito mode, but simply users which might not be logged into Facebook, or have never even used it in the first place. The latter can hardly have given their consent to any data collection by Facebook, but when you embed their social plugins that already happens to a certain degree (“shadow profiles”)

Comment: I get that, but there's no proof for me to check if a shadow profile has personal information on a user. I've hidden the buttons without consent, but in the end shadow profiles have nothing to do with our scope in the GDPR and since there aren't any cookies set there isn't much more I can do about that.

Comment: Looks like Facebook has made changes in that regard too, it used to be that the social plugins set cookies even if there isn’t a logged-in Facebook user, IIRC. // We have some websites run on behalf of government agencies that are extra strict in regard to this - they aren’t even happy with just the fact that the IP address of a user visiting our sites would automatically be “send” to Facebook’s servers when we embed a social plugin, so we need to have the 2-click solution just for that already. But that’s probably more than GDPR actually demands.

Comment: I can totally understand that! It seems that in this case that doesn't seem to happen. Every cookie that is set while incognito is either anonimized google analytics  data or cookies set by myself :)